# Как выбрать все файлы в названии которых есть p1?

Tags: php

В папке несколько тысяч файлов, и мне нужно выбрать лишь те, в азвании которых присутствует `p1`, реально ли такое сделать с помощью PHP? Например, чтобы такие файлы скопировать в другую папку.

Comment: Реально. Сканируйте необходимый каталог, и сохраняйте имена только тех файлов, которые начинаются с `p1`.

Comment: Занести их в массив и потом скопировать их всех в отдельную папку?

Comment: Вы можете использовать `shell_exec`. Думаю, что с ним будет легче.

Comment: @LEQADA, легче не будет. А вот потенциальные проблемы с безопасностью вы получите наверняка

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, легче будет, потому что через терминал такие операции выполнять всё же проще. Он создан для таких операций. И насчёт безопасности не согласен. Если правильно использовать, то никаких проблем не будет.

Comment: @LEQADA, вы позволяете выполнять shell команды из PHP. Это _дыра_ в безопасности. PHP богатый яп (иногда даже слишком) и не нужно лепить костыли на пустом месте

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, зависит от поставленной задачи. Никакой дыры не будет, если правильно использовать.

Comment: @LEQADA, надеюсь мне никогда не придется поддерживать ваш код ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вашу задачу можно разбить на два логических куска:

1. Обход директории с файлами
2. Определение файлов, чьи имена начинаются с заданной строки.

Для решения первой части проблемы, в PHP существует связка операторов [`opendir`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.opendir.php), [`readdir`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.readdir.php) и [`closedir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.closedir.php). А работает это примерно так:

```
$dh = opendir('каталог, который нужно читать');
while ($file = readdir($dh)) {
    // $file это имя файла/директории относительно открытой директории.
    if ($file === '..' || $file === '.') {
        // Откидываем родительский и текущий каталоги.
        continue;
    }

    // ...
    // Выполняем необходимые операции
    // ...
}
closedir($dh);
```

Проверку на то, начинается ли строка с каких-то символов можно выполнить через [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php), например, так:

```
// Поиск будет проводится в этой строке
$target = 'test_123';
// Обратите внимание на оператор эквивалентности. Это важно
if (strpos($target, 'test') === 0) {
    // Строка в переменной $target начинается с "test"
}
```

Comment: Допустим, я нашел все эти файлы, а потом мне нужно их имена занести в массив, и потом через цикл с помощью функции `copy` скопировать их в отдельную папку? мысль правильная?)

Comment: @emtecif, да, в целом, правильная. Разумеется имеет смысл добавить проверку, является ли текущая запись файлом или каталогом. `readdir`  не делает между ними различий ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$files = glob("/path/to/your/dir/(*p1*)"));
    foreach($files as $file) {
      if(is_file($file))
        bool copy ( string $file , string $another_folder_path)
    }
```

1) в $files получаем массив названий с p1, (изменил немного)
2) для каждого File проверяем на существование
3) И делаем что хотим - копируем из пути file в директорию another_folder_path
Если целевой файл уже существует, то он будет перезаписан.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php
Давно не php-шил, но должно сработать (разве что регулярка может плеваться).

Comment: А зачем вы указываете `bool` и `string`? ;)

Comment: Ну я же говорю Дмитрий, давно не пхп-шил :D ;)